# "What I'd held in my hand was..." or "What I held in my hand had been?"

Tags: grammar, past-tense

Which is the correct form? Should I write:

> My teacher said I had stumbled upon a colony of ants, that an
>   anteater or some other animal had probably made the hole in an
>   attempt to eat them. **And that what I'd held in my hand was an
>   exploding ant.**

Or

> My teacher said I had stumbled upon a colony of ants, that an
>   anteater or some other animal had probably made the hole in an
>   attempt to eat them. **And that what I held in my hand had been an
>   exploding ant.**

Answer (score 1):

Well, both sentences are correct, but they have a different meaning:

> What I'd held in my hand was an exploding ant.

You are no longer holding it in your hand, but at the time your are referring to, the ant was in the act of exploding.

So, you pick up something, put it down, and it then turns into an exploding ant. (Do they tend to explode?)

> What I held in my hand had been an exploding ant.

Whatever you are holding at the time you are referring to, it is no longer an exploding ant. It is likely to be the *remains* of that ant, or — as I am not familiar with ants exploding — a nice cold drink.

So, you are holding a drink in your hand, but you realize that that drink used to be an exploding ant.

Comment: Thanks for spotting that. I changed it to `anteater`.